# MS WORD TOC : How to put a different color before or after the character ":" in the titles?

Tags: vba, ms-word, tableofcontents

I have a text document in Word with several parts, I have created my table of contents. I created a TOC to be able to update it automatically, it is used for that.
By alt+F9 I have TOC \O "1-2" \H \U

You can see the sign \H that I need to have the links to the headers.

I can in the headers apply the desired color before and after the two points of my titles which are the form :
[xxxxx xxxx xxxx : (red)] [yyyyy yyyyy yyyyy (black)]

I want this color difference to show up in my summary (TOC) as well. So I add the instruction \* MERGEFORMAT
This gives : TOC \O "1-2" \* MERGEFORMAT \H \U

However, by doing this, I lose my links, as the instruction \H is no longer valid.

**So I switched to VBA code.**

But I don't know how to say :
xxxxxxx (in red) : xxxxxx (in black)

The x is variable, and the two points ( : ) is always present in my titles in the headers.
What would be the code to say that from the 2 points ( : ) the rest of the titles must be in black color. OR that before the 2 points ( : ) the color of the titles must be in red ?

For example:

Example/title: (in red) Here is my title (in black)

Example title two: (in red) Here is my second example (in black)

Other/example/additional: (in red) This is the last title (in black)

Thank you for your insights

EDIT :

Hi,

```
`Dim I As Integer, J As Integer
 Dim MonTableau As Variant
 Dim ListePositionsMots As String
 Dim MonRange As Range


With ActiveDocument

     If .TablesOfContents.Count = 0 Then
        MsgBox "Aucune table des matières dans le document !", vbInformation
        Exit Sub
     End If

     With .TablesOfContents(1)
          J = 1
          For I = 1 To .Range.Words.Count
              If J <= 2 Then
                 If .Range.Words(I) <> "" Then ListePositionsMots = ListePositionsMots & I & ","
                 J = J + 1
              End If
              If .Range.Words(I) = Chr(13) Then J = 1
          Next I

          ListePositionsMots = Mid(ListePositionsMots, 1, Len(ListePositionsMots) - 1)
          MonTableau = Split(ListePositionsMots, ",")
          For I = LBound(MonTableau) To UBound(MonTableau)
              Set MonRange = ActiveDocument.TablesOfContents(1).Range
              MonRange.SetRange Start:=MonRange.Words(MonTableau(I)).Start, End:=MonRange.Words(MonTableau(I)).End
              With MonRange
                   If .Text <> Chr(9) Then
                      .Font.ColorIndex = wdRed
                      .Case = wdUpperCase
                    End If
              End With
              Set MonRange = Nothing
          Next I

      End With
End With`
```

Good evening,

The above code works very well and allows me to colour the first 2 words of each of my titles in my table of contents.

x y (red) : x y z (black)

v w (red) : y z (black)

So it's possible.

As sometimes my titles exceed 2 words, I have to modify it.
I have to put **the value of the word** ; in this case the 2 points caracters ( : ) and not its position.

x y z (red) **:** (red or black)  x y z (black)

But I don't know what vba code can do that, that's why I'm asking on this forum, I'm sure someone can help me?

Thanks.

EDIT 2 (26/05/2021 10:45) : I repeat, I just need the VBA code, nothing more, nothing less... Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code below will apply the color you require. To capitalise the TOC you should modify the font for your TOC styles to AllCaps

```
Sub ColorTOC()
   Dim tocRange As Range

   With ActiveDocument

      If .TablesOfContents.Count = 0 Then
         MsgBox "Aucune table des matières dans le document !", vbInformation
      Else
         With .TablesOfContents(1)
            Set tocRange = .Range.Duplicate
            tocRange.Collapse wdCollapseStart
            Do Until tocRange.End = .Range.End
               tocRange.MoveEndUntil ":"
               tocRange.MoveEnd wdCharacter, 1
               With tocRange
                  If .Text <> Chr(9) Then
                     .Font.ColorIndex = wdRed
                  End If
               End With
               tocRange.Collapse wdCollapseEnd
               tocRange.MoveUntil vbCr
               tocRange.Move wdCharacter, 1
            Loop
         End With
      End If
   End With
End Sub
```

When a TOC is updated the dialog below is displayed.

[image: Update Table of Contents dialog]

Choosing the first option will not cause the formatting to be lost, but the TOC will ***not*** include any newly added headings. The second option will include any newly added headings, *but it will also remove the formatting*.

If the document has the "Update fields before printing" option set (it should to ensure that page numbers etc. are correct) then the user will be prompted to update the TOC. This will occur both prior to printing and exporting as PDF. To ensure that your TOC has the correct formatting you will need to write code to respond to the `DocumentBeforePrint` event so that you can reapply the formatting.

Comment: Thanks Timothy, it's a nice change from the headache of Macropod. But I can't say that your solution works because my word crashes with your macro. I am cursed.

Comment: @JeaDujar -  your other option is to remove the \h switch. Then you will have the formatting you want and the page numbers will still have hyperlinks. You could then use the built-in "Publish as PDF or XPS" command and choose the option to create bookmarks from headings. This will result in a pdf that has better navigation options than just a TOC.

Comment: I don't know if I'm making myself clear. I'm telling you, it's written in black and white, that I want the links on the titles of my summary. Why do you want to force me to remove the links? That's not what I'm asking for....

Comment: @JeaDujar - There is no need to take that tone. I am simply outlining alternative options to you that you may not have considered, and that will avoid you crashing Word.

Comment: @ Timothy Rylatt   YES Thanks You Timothy, Your VBA code works ! Thank you, it works perfectly: I have my text in red up to the 2 points and I always have the links when I click on the titles, thank you really. Timothy, you have my gratitude.

Comment: @ Timothy : Sorry for my previous tone, it's because of macropod.

Comment: I did not cause you to be rude - that was entirely your own decision.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need any code for this. Without the \H switch, a Table of Contents will automatically reproduce any font colouring you apply to a Heading. At most, all you need to do is to refresh the Table of Contents.

Even without the \H switch, your Table of Contents will link to the referenced content via the page #s. All the \H switch does is enable the linking from the Table of Contents text.

In any event, it would be a waste of time trying to apply colouring to the Table of Contents with VBA (or manually), since anything that causes the Table of Contents to refresh (e.g. a print preview or printing the document) will erase all that colouring.

In any event, you don't even need a macro to colour the Table of Contents as you describe - all you need is a single *wildcard* Find/Replace operation on the Table of Contents, where:
Find = [!^t^13]@:
Replace = ^&
and you set the replacement colour to red. You could, of course, implement that as a macro, but I can't see why anyone would bother...

Comment: :This is not a good answer: look my post. You don't answer the question: what is the VBA code to automatically put the words before or after the two points in a different colour while keeping the links

Comment: It *does* keep the links. Kindly read my *whole* answer. Kindly also pay attention to what I said about your proposed VBA solution and the consequences of doing anything that results in the TOC refreshing. You not liking the answer just because you're wedded to a VBA non-solution doesn't not make it any less an answer. Especially to the question as *originally* posed.

Comment: No, following your advice, when I replace the TOC "1-2"\H \U by simply TOC, the document takes my headers in colors of course, BUT does not keep the links : when I click on my titles nothing happens. I do have a cross-reference with the page number, yes, but that's not my question: I never talked about page numbers but about headers, and when I save as a PDF I don't have any links.